# Google Map is not shown on Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a Wordpress Contact page where i would like to display a Google Map. I use this Javascript in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=de"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rendererOptions = { draggable: true };
var map;
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(48.100037,11.787567);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

// Initalize your map
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:zoom,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      center: start
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

// Collect entered data and open Google Maps in a new browser tab
function showRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var dest_url = "http://maps.google.de/maps?saddr="+start+"&daddr="+destination;
    window.open(dest_url, '_blank');
}
</script>

<script>
// Define infobox widget
function codeAddress() {
    var address = destination;
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(start);
        var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<p style='margin-bottom:5px;padding-bottom:0;'>Geben Sie Ihre Adresse ein und dr&uuml;cken Sie auf 'Start'</p><p style='font-size:12px;color:grey;margin:0 0 15px 0;padding:0;'>Beispiel: Marktplatz 1, 85598 Baldham</p><input id='address' type='textbox' value='' style='border: 1px solid #000; width:230px;'> <input type='button' value='Start' onClick='showRoute();'><br />&nbsp;",
        map: map,
        position: start
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode not available: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

</script>

<script>
// DO NOT CHANGE CODE ABOVE!

// Change custom parameters starting from here:
var zoom = 18; // map zoom
var destination = "Marktplatz 1, 85598 Baldham"; // destination, your address
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.width = '710px'; // map width
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.height = '600px'; // map height
initialize();
codeAddress();
</script>
```

On the Wordpress page i am using this:

```
<div id="googlemap"><div id="map_canvas"></div></div>
```

Unfortunately the map is not shown but i don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really easy. Located in the header, the javascript tries to access an object of the DOM that is not available. I moved the javascript before the closing body tag and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in your Google maps javascript, it works for me. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2483om3L/)

```
var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true
};
var map;
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(48.100037, 11.787567);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

// Initalize your map
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        center: start
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

// Collect entered data and open Google Maps in a new browser tab
function showRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var dest_url = "http://maps.google.de/maps?saddr=" + start + "&daddr=" + destination;
    window.open(dest_url, '_blank');
}

// Define infobox widget
function codeAddress() {
    var address = destination;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(start);
            var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<p style='margin-bottom:5px;padding-bottom:0;'>Geben Sie Ihre Adresse ein und dr&uuml;cken Sie auf 'Start'</p><p style='font-size:12px;color:grey;margin:0 0 15px 0;padding:0;'>Beispiel: Marktplatz 1, 85598 Baldham</p><input id='address' type='textbox' value='' style='border: 1px solid #000; width:230px;'> <input type='button' value='Start' onClick='showRoute();'><br />&nbsp;",
                map: map,
                position: start
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode not available: " + status);
        }
    });
}

// DO NOT CHANGE CODE ABOVE!

// Change custom parameters starting from here:
var zoom = 18; // map zoom
var destination = "Marktplatz 1, 85598 Baldham"; // destination, your address
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.width = '710px'; // map width
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.height = '600px'; // map height
initialize();
codeAddress();
```

A few suggestions to check

- Check debug console for javascript errors preventing google maps api to execute
- Css styling preventing the map to be visible